# New MacBook Pro Retina Hard Drive Type

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I'm looking to buy a 15" Retina MacBook Pro, I'm looking at the website [Models](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro/select) and they seem to be pretty inflexible (for instance the 2.3 GHz model you are locked into a 256 GB HD).

So I know this is a little preemptive, but I want to know how the hard drive is configured. For instance, on my current MacBook Pro I swapped out the standard hard drive for a 480 GB SSD. If the new thinner model has a standard SSD I will buy the 2.3 GHz model and add larger hard drive. My worry is it will use a proprietary hard drive like those found in the Air in which case I would be forced to buy the 2.6 GHz model just to get the larger storage I suppose.

Does anyone have any info on this?

Comment: I don't think there is anything concrete, but from the picture of the inside it looks to be the same as with the Air models (i.e. there is nothing to replace manually, neither RAM nor hard drives).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flash modules and controller of the SSD are blades (think naked SSD). They are not up to 3rd party configuration (at this time), but according to [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53508/7833), they are not soldered onto the main board and are actually discrete components.

However, there is no information as to what kind of proprietary (if any) configuration the blades come in, or whether they require an additional proprietary onboard controller (this may be likely given Apple's tendency to create speciality hardware for their line-up). So it most likely isn't the case that one could just crack open an existing SSD and use the blades within. A manufacturer would have to specifically design a unit for the new notebook. This isn't unlikely, but price will be the determining factor as it will be a speciality component.

It is also not clear at this time if Apple will make the components upgradeable, which is also a distinct possibility given how quickly SSDs are saturating the market place.

At best, it's a tentative "maybe."

[image]

You can read more about the new machine here: http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/design/

Comment: Where did you get the picture ?  Sure it is the pro (not doubting just disappointing as I have to drop an extra 1000 on a feature I don't need)

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna Image courtesy of Apple: http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/design/

Comment: I see it now, wow this is next level predatory pricing even for apple.

Comment: Darn! I wish you could replace them. Looks like no Retina MacBook for me (or right now, at least)

Comment: Apple has long put out new models at often the same or cheaper price points. They have been working towards this from, you could say, day one. Like the MBA and the iPhone (iPad and iPod Touch), the new MBP now falls in line. The tighter the hardware integration, the better the software optimization. This is why comparable devices from other manufacturers require up to 40% more hardware power to compete with Apple products (the Samsung Galaxy, with it's 1.2 GHz CPU couldn't beat the weaker armed iPhone 4 in tests).

Comment: Ha, I've never heard Apple accused of "predatory pricing" for their Macs before.  (This page is already the first google hit for: apple mac "predatory pricing".)  They must be doing something right these days when people think a $2100-2700 laptop is so cheap that it will drive competitors out of business.

Comment: @Ken calling Apple products "overpriced" is the only thing PC manufacturers have in their arsenal these days. They churn out crap but always tote that their hardware is equivalent. Things are poorly built, cumbersome, and hard to use. Like a Ferrari is a car like any other car. The iPhone 4S has a 10 megapixel camera and so does our phone, but Apple's implementation comes with far superior optics and that makes all the difference. No one else could even reproduce the Retina display. PC makers always hide behind marketing, but they loose Honda Civics, while Apple looses Ferraris.

Comment: cksum: Yes, that is the traditional accusation about Apple, but here the complaint was "predatory pricing", i.e., intentional *underpricing*.

Comment: According to [bmike's answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53508/7833), the SSD is *is* upgradable, and not soldered into the logic board. However, as of right now, there are no third party SSDs...

Comment: @daviesgeek thanks for the heads up. I guess it comes down to what manufacturer is going to produce blade SSD modules for the machine and if it will be cheaper than Apple's offerings. However, that does mean one could technically upgrade through Apple without any issues (unlike the Air). I'm wondering if cracking open existing SSD could provide a suitable replacement (if they are the same form factor or if Apple has a unique one)?

Comment: Me too. I'm really excited about these new MacBook Pros, but I'm a bit concerned about upgrading.

Comment: @daviesgeek At a $2,500 investment, not being able to upgrade the hard drive is a bit of a sore spot. Getting it with 16 GB will ensure future proofing for the next several years (even 8 GB is sufficient), but the hard drive is another story. I'm thinking Apple may introduce upgrade hardware (hopefully).

Comment: Yes. I am really limited by that factor. I need the extra on-board space, and not having it is a key factor in (possibly) buying one of these.

Comment: Just to clarify - some people seem confused as to whether the SSD is "soldered". The chips that make up the storage are certainly surface mounted and permanently affixed to the card that itself is a replaceable unit. Apple doesn't expose the manufacturer of the cards, so we may have to wait a bit to see how likely an upgrade path might become.

Comment: @bmike Fleshed out my answer a little to add what I was driving at when I said "speciality controller."

Comment: @Ken What I meant by predatory pricing had nothing to do with price itself , rather, it is the fact that the base (2.3) model is not customizable whatsoever forcing people to spend 1000 dollars more to get a decent amount of storage.  This is a marketing scheme and takes away from  the value of the brand IMO.

Answer (score 1):

OWC are now offering 480GB replacement SSD modules specifically for the Retina MacbookPro.

http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Aura_Pro_Retina_2012

They are not a standard form factor, (and still a long way off being considered 'cheap') but at least it means that a route to increasing capacity from 256 to 480GB exists.

Answer (score -2):

The new MacBookPro from Apple uses flash memory directly embedded on to circuit board and currently not replaceable.

P.S. This is part of the reason that the new model is so thin.