# Is the retina Macbook Pro's SSD soldered into the logic board?

Tags: ssd, macbook-pro

The Macbook Air's SSD can be [manually upgraded](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2011/05/review-supersize-your-macbook-air-ssd-with-owcs-aura-pro-express/).

The RAM of the Macbook Air and [retina MBP however are soldered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53450/13414) into the logic board.

## Question

Is the retina Macbook Pro's SSD soldered into the logic board as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No - The SSD card is a discrete component on the new retina MacBook Pro and can be ordered as an Apple service part. Time will tell if an aftermarket supplier decides to supply parts for that model.

Even though it's not soldered, it still is not a user-servicable part.

As ArsTechnica [reports](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/06/retina-macbook-pro-full-of-air-style-proprietary-parts/):

> While Apple uses the latest SATA protocol, the connector is *physically incompatible with either Mini PCIe or mSATA*.

Comment: so this tweet is wrong: https://twitter.com/unimp0rtanttech/status/212531887313399808 ?

Comment: That tweet seems more about the communication protocol than whether the part is physically soldered or connected by multi-use contacts or pins. The tweet's truth doesn't seem germane to the discussion here. (the other tweet by that author saying SSD is soldered to the MLB is dead wrong. Perhaps the tweeter is confusing RAM with SSD)

Comment: he follows with this tweet: https://twitter.com/unimp0rtanttech/status/212533278920540161 which mentions soldering.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the SSD is removeable. **Notice the connector on the right and the single screw on the left.**

The [iFixit teardown has been completed for the Retina MacBook Pro](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Pro-with-Retina-Display-Teardown/9462/1) and confirms that the SSD is removable and its a new proprietary design and form factor.

[image: Apple Picture edited to highlight the SSD Flash Drive location]

The picture is provided by Apple and shows the bottom of the laptop and reveals the internals: http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/design/

Comment: I want to disassemble and pour over the internals of this sexy new beast so badly right now. Thanks for the picture!

Comment: The screws! That's just like on the Macbook Air. I'm pretty sure this is it.

Comment: As bmike notes and as can be observer-ed from the OP's OWC link this new MacBooks SSD is a different SSD  form factor than what is in the MacBook Airs.

Comment: @bmike… ifixit.

Answer (score -1):

Though I can't cite any facts, but due to the similarities and the engineering behind the product to give us such a thin form factor. I doubt it. I foresee the RAM being user accessible, not the SSD ( like the Air)
We really wont' know til iFixit.com puts our a guide.